# Objective-c class design/organization

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've created my first iPhone app that presents audio tracks of a similar genre in  a tableview. The user can play audio tracks using ipod-like controls which streams mp3.

All of my code is in two main classes: `RootViewController` and `CustomCell`.

My `RootViewControllerClass` is massive. I'm assuming it is poor design to stuff almost all of my code in one class?

Initially, I thought it made sense because I only have one View Controller. To practice better coding conventions, I'd like to split up my `RootViewController` class into smaller, specific classes (assuming this is the correct practice?).

Here are the components of `RootViewController` that I plan to separate out into individual classes:

- `DataSource` - pulls data from server; modifies and organizes the data for the tableView
- `TopChartsView` - includes buttons in a view to modify the audio tracks(dataSource) by top rated weekly/monthly/all-time
- `GenreChange` - includes buttons in a view to filter the dataSource by genre
- `AudioPlayerControls` - includes buttons in a view that are similar to iPod controls

Am I organizing my classes correctly? It seems to make sense that I organize my classes by function. However, I'm having difficulty grasping how classes should interact with each other in an ideal design.

Do I use protocols and delegation to link my classes together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more about object-oriented-programming than especially about iOS and I think, you should get familiar with some concepts of OO-Design (if you really interested), but from my point of view you don't have to. To answer your questions first:

> I'm assuming it is poor design to stuff almost all of my code in one class?

Some say so...

> Am I organizing my classes correctly?

Hard to tell, by the information you gave.

> Do I use protocols and delegation to link my classes together?

Not necessarily.

**But**: If your code works fine, you are the only one, who works on it, you don't plan to re-use your code as a library or by taking full classes from it (i.e. if you only plan to copy & paste), there is no need to refactoring everything just for the sake of doing it.

**Even though**: If you want to move forward or if you're planning to write libraries or something, it would be a good idea to learn about OO (sometimes it's even entertaining). Since you're working with objective-c [this one from apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html) could be a good start to learn.

**And**: If you read a bit about OO-programming and (more important) take the time and to read code of others, you'll know how and when it is useful to organize your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Designing iOS apps is mostly about the MVC design pattern, which means that you seperate your model, view and controller. In your case I would put the DataSource logic in a seperate file or files (it's your model). This also makes it easier to reuse the same logic in another view controller in a later point. Maybe you can also subclass your UITableView if lots of code resides there.

Protocols and delegates are a great way to connect your classes and they are very frequently used in a good design. Since you don't have many viewcontrollers in your application (as far as I see), there are not very much opportunities to use them, please correct me if I'm wrong ;)